# Hide clicked buttons and show images in memory image game Java

Tags: java

I want to make a memory card game and I am thinking in a very basic way. So I add labels that holding images and add buttons above them, what I need to know is after clicking two buttons how to hide the clicked buttons and show the images and disable the remaining buttons

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class Buttons extends JFrame{
    JButton b1, b2, b3, b4;
    JLabel labe11, label2, label3, label4;
    public Buttons(){
        setLayout(null);
        Icon icon1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("tiger.png"));
        Icon icon2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("chicken.png"));
        Icon icon3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("pink watercolor 2.png"));
        b1 = new JButton();
        b2 = new JButton();
        b3 = new JButton();
        b4 = new JButton();
        b1.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 140);
        b2.setBounds(350, 100, 200, 140);
        b3.setBounds(100, 300, 200, 140);
        b4.setBounds(350, 300, 200, 140);

        labe11 = new JLabel(icon1);
        label2 = new JLabel(icon2);
        label3 = new JLabel(icon2);
        label4 = new JLabel(icon3);

        labe11.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 140);
        label2.setBounds(350, 100, 200, 140);
        label3.setBounds(100, 300, 200, 140);
        label4.setBounds(350, 300, 200, 140);
        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(b3);
        add(b4);
        add(labe11);
        add(label2);
        add(label3);
        add(label4);
        ButtonsListener handler = new ButtonsListener();
        b1.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    public void matched(JButton b1, JButton b2){
        if (b1.getIcon() == b2.getIcon()){
            //set the icon visible and disable the button
        }
    }

    private class ButtonsListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach an `ActionListener` listener to each one of those `JButton`'s.

1. You don't need to create `ButtonsListener`, you can make `Buttons`
   class implement that,

`public class Buttons extends JFrame implements ActionListener`

2. You need some references to remember which button was pressed last
   and if the user tapped a pair of buttons,

```
int buttonsPressed = 0;
JButton lastPressed = null;
```

3. Attach the listener to the buttons of your interest (now the `ActionListener` is the `Buttons` class so the listener is `this`, the `Button` class),

```
b1.addActionListener(this);
b2.addActionListener(this);
b3.addActionListener(this);
b4.addActionListener(this);
```

4. Handle the logic to `actionPerformed`. Whenever it finds a match of buttons it calls `onMatch()`,

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (++buttonsPressed == 2) {
            matched(lastPressed, (JButton) e.getSource());
            buttonsPressed = 0;
        }else{
            lastPressed = (JButton) e.getSource();
        }
    }
```

Here's the whole file,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Buttons extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton b1, b2, b3, b4;
    JLabel labe11, label2, label3, label4;

    int buttonsPressed = 0;
    JButton lastPressed = null;

    public Buttons(){
        setLayout(null);
        Icon icon1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("tiger.png"));
        Icon icon2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("chicken.png"));
        Icon icon3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("pink watercolor 2.png"));
        b1 = new JButton();
        b2 = new JButton();
        b3 = new JButton();
        b4 = new JButton();
        b1.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 140);
        b2.setBounds(350, 100, 200, 140);
        b3.setBounds(100, 300, 200, 140);
        b4.setBounds(350, 300, 200, 140);

        // Attach the listener to the buttons
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b4.addActionListener(this);

        labe11 = new JLabel(icon1);
        label2 = new JLabel(icon2);
        label3 = new JLabel(icon2);
        label4 = new JLabel(icon3);

        labe11.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 140);
        label2.setBounds(350, 100, 200, 140);
        label3.setBounds(100, 300, 200, 140);
        label4.setBounds(350, 300, 200, 140);
        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(b3);
        add(b4);
        add(labe11);
        add(label2);
        add(label3);
        add(label4);
        ButtonsListener handler = new ButtonsListener();
        b1.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    public void matched(JButton b1, JButton b2){
        if (b1.getIcon() == b2.getIcon()){
            //set the icon visible and disable the button
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (++buttonsPressed == 2) {
            matched(lastPressed, (JButton) e.getSource());
            buttonsPressed = 0;
        }else{
            lastPressed = (JButton) e.getSource();
        }
    }
}
```